# How to implement XML comment to show a hint in ASP.NET in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm working on some maintenance of already developed Web Application in ASP.NET in C#.

There I saw following code block of XML comment. I know why this XML comment using in C#. But I don't know how to implement this code block ! Weather it is auto generated or is there any other way ?

```
/// <summary>
///    This is a Login Attempt Class
/// </summary>
public void GetLoginAttempts(){}
```

Please help me..

Comment: VS will create that if you type a triple slash `///`

Comment: You type `///` and enter your comment... What's your question?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. If you type "///" above a method that doesn't contain an XML comment, VS will create an empty summary for you. Is that what you're asking about? (This doesn't really have anything to do with ASP.NET by the way.)

Comment: Ok. I got the point. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press /// above a method in Visual Studio, it will automatically generate the XML structure for that method. It will also add for all the parameters.

Usages:

1. How To comments, for method, parameters and return type. [image]
2. One benefit is, when you use the method, Visual Studio will show you tool tip.
   [image]
3. Another benefit, when you switch ON the XML documentation file, It will generate XML documentation based on the comments.
   [image]

Comment: I got the expected explanation from you @Sunil. Showing the tool tip is useful. What is the usefulness of generating XML documentation based on the comments ?

Comment: XML documentation can be used to document your API. If someone ask you on how to use your API or DLL you can give them this document instead of preparing one from scratch. If this answers your question why not mark it as answer.

Comment: _I'm new to Stackoverflow_. Could you please tell me how to mark it as answer ? Is it by click on the upward arrow (This answer is useful)

Comment: If it is useful you can also vote up. To mark as answer follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. **Choose one answer** that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.